# convert pdf forms to regular pdf

Tags: pdf, forms

Smart pdf's are nice, but most people wouldn't know what to do when their browser would not load them. A conversion to regular pdf, ditching the forms and functions is desirable.

Can that be done ? How ?

Comment: Can't you just 'print' them to a 'PDF printer' to remove all those unwanted extra's ?  (e.g. http:// http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator and similar programs )

Comment: Can't I ? I am doing it.Now, can't you just 'answer' the regular way ?

Comment: Done. I assumed it was too short and trivial as a full answer. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install a 'PDF printer'. That is a virtual printer. Printing to it asks you for a filename and the result ends up in a PDF file.

Printing to such a PDF printer strips all field functionality.

The one I personally use is [pdfcreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator), but there are many similar programs.

Warning: Should you test the one I linked to, make sure you untick the 'helpful software' bar. Do not just [next][next][next][Finish].

Answer (score 0):

In Acrobat Pro ree save the PDF as an optimised PDF and check 'flatten form fields' under the 'Discard Objects' menu. Also explained here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HjubmMrZacE

Comment: Link only answer say what!!!